# GitExtensions - It says there are conflicts but in reality there aren't

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am using gitExtensions. I have some changes in my local and until now when I opened the repo with GitExtensions it was working ok. It was displaying all the commits for that repo. Now when I open that Repo GitExtensions displays following screen and If I click on resolve button, no file conflicts appear listed.

[image]

UPDATE:
I have discovered why GitExtensions displays that screen. After updating Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.9 to v16.11.15, git is updated to version 2.36.0.windows.1 and with this versions of Git, GitExtensions is not working and consequently showing that screen. Also for GitExtensions a simple Git fetch is not working. Previous to update Visual Studio 2019, my git version was 2.33.0.windows.2 and GitExtensions was working without problemas. So the culprit is the Git version. It seems like GitExtensions is not compatible with Git version 2.36.0.windows.1 So how to make GitExtensions work with Git version 2.36.0.windows.1????

My GitExtensions is the last version: 3.5.4.12724

This is what apperas en GitExtensions About:

- Git Extensions 3.5.4.12724
- Build 65f01f39982ccb121c4df7d4b00b506939553958
- Git 2.36.0.windows.1
- Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22000.0
- .NET Framework 4.8.4510.0
- DPI 192dpi (200% scaling)

Comment: Please use command line got commands to show you status of repository. Copy paste content of `git bash` for flowing commands: `git status` `git branch` `git diff`. It is easier to explain problem and provide answers in terms of git commands instead specific git UI fronted.

Comment: @MarekR git status says I have some modified files. That's correct. Using git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U displays nothing so why UI frontend is saying there are conflicts?

Comment: @MarekR I have discovered why GitExtensions displays that screen. After updating Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.9 to v16.11.15, git is updated to version 2.36.0.windows.1 and with this versions of Git, GitExtensions is not working and consequently showing that screen. Also for GitExtensions a simple Git fetch is not working. Previous to update Visual Studio 2019, my git version was 2.33.0.windows.2 and GitExtensions was working without problemas. So the culprit is the Git version. It seems like GitExtensions is not compatible with Git version 2.36.0.windows.1

Comment: I have downgraded git to version 2.34.1.windows.1 and now GitExtensions works and that damn screen is not shown saying there are conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Discussed in GitExtensions github: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/9979#issuecomment-1109561831

The issue is that you set a config setting 'core.usebuiltinfsmonitor' that will be deprecated.

And so git display a 'hint' in the output of a command that GitExtensions expect to be empty (to check if there are merge conflicts) and so interpret badly the output.

The good fix is to unset this setting (and use the replacing one if you wish 'core.fsmonitor')